# correlation controlling for baseline scores

Tags: correlation, partial-correlation

I just got a review back on paper and the reviewers want me to report a correlation between the variable at time one and time two controlling for baseline scores.  Is a correlation that includes a control for baseline scores possible, or can that only be done using SEM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is "partial correlation". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation - the introductory statement of that page (as of today: Aug 21, 2016) is

> In probability theory and statistics, partial correlation measures the degree of association between two random variables, with the effect of a set of controlling random variables removed.

Comment: And partial correlation is usually estimated using regression models